# Getting "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution" error when using docker-compose to build containers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, dns

It seems as if my php container cannot resolve the host "db" of my database container when I run `php artisan migrate`, I'm wondering if I've set something up wrong in the config.

Tried messing with the depends_on: and links: options on the dockerfile.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: tasks-db
    image: mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=tasks
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    restart: always

  webserver:
    container_name: tasks-webserver
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./provision/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    depends_on:
      - php
    restart: always

  php:
    container_name: tasks-php
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: provision/php.docker
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

provision/db.docker

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Add dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl libpng-dev libxml2-dev curl cron git libzip-dev zip unzip

# Install php extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring gd xml pdo_mysql zip

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN chown -R $USER:www-data /app/storage
RUN chown -R $USER:www-data /app/bootstrap/cache

RUN chmod -R 775 /app/storage
RUN chmod -R 775 /app/bootstrap/cache

# Install composer dependencies
RUN composer install

RUN php artisan optimize

#RUN php artisan migrate --seed

RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * php /app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1"; } | crontab -

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

db.docker

```
FROM mariadb:latest

CMD ["mysqld", "--user=mysql"]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Step 13/16 : RUN php artisan migrate --no-interaction --seed
 ---> Running in ccbfcde9324d

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = tasks and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution")
      /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=tasks", "root", "password", [])
      /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c php artisan migrate --no-interaction --seed' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: You cannot access other services from within a Dockerfile, and you cannot run database migrations at image build time.  (What if you destroy and recreate the database, but don’t rebuild the image?)  The linked question has an entrypoint-based solution which should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing

```
  links:
    - db
```

in your `php` configuration.

Anyway as @David Maze mentioned, running `php artisan migrate` in a Dockerfile is not only a bad practice, but it will not work.

You should run that command only when your containers are started. Think about it, `php artisan migrate` will modify another container's data, which is not guaranteed it is running at the time the image is being built. That is against the container philosophy.